# Scrapy: ImportError: No module named items

Tags: python, scrapy

When I try to run scrapy I get this error ImportError: No module named items

I just added in items.py the list of things I want to scrape and in the spider.py I have imported the class with from spider.items import SpiderItem

Dont know why its not loading it...

Package layout is...

```
./spider
./spider/pipelines.py
./spider/settings.py
./spider/spiders
./spider/spiders/spider_spider.py
./spider/spiders/test.py
./spider/spiders/__init__.py
./spider/middlewares.py
./spider/__init__.py
./spider/items.py
```

Comment: your middle sencence makes no sense. you probably have a problem with (relative) imports. you should post your package layout, then maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [this message on google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/msg/13e4127878714417):

Your spider module is named the same as your scrapy project module, so
python is trying to import items relative to byub.py spider.

You are facing a common regret of python imports, see
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328

quicks fixes:

- rename your spider module to byub_org.py or similar.
- or use `from __future__ import absolute_import` in byub.py spider.
- or rename your project to something like byubbot.

Comment: Thanks Nick but I have already found that and tried to solve it... and that was not the issue or at least I am not getting a solution...

Answer (score 4):

I happend to face this problem because my spider name is the same with the scrapy project.

Just rename the spider name will make it.

Comment: Had the same issue, I renamed the spider name file different than the project and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Without renaming any files, change `from spider.items import SpiderItem` to `from .. import items` and refer to the item as `items.SpiderItem` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good solution to rename your spider module.

**But don't forget to delete the related `*.pyc` file after renaming**, considering that the `*.pyc` file plays a role like **cache**.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroposting. Try put in file 
`./spider/__init__.py`

that

```
 import items
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following line after your import statements in your spider.py file.

class ProjectnamegoeshereSpider(BaseSpider):