# scrapy error ImportError: No module named items

Tags: python, linux, terminal, scrapy, web-crawler

i want to crawler website [this link](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/pc?page=0)
but when i crawler using command

```
scrapy crawl metacritic -o metacritic.json -t json
```

its says `ImportError: No module named items`
does anybody can help?

metacritic_spider.py source :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
class MetacriticSpider(BaseSpider):
class MetacriticSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "metacritic" # Name of the spider, to be used when crawling
    allowed_domains = ["metacritic.com"] # Where the spider is allowed to go
    start_urls = ["http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/pc?page=0"]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) # The XPath selector
        sites = hxs.select('//li[contains(@class, "product game_product")]/div[@class="product_wrap"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = MetacriticItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_title"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_title"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['cscore'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_score brief_metascore"]/div/div/span[contains(@class, "data metascore score")]/text()').extract()
            item['uscore'] = site.select('div[@class="more_stats condensed_stats"]/ul/li/span[contains(@class, "data textscore textscore")]/text()').extract()
            item['date'] = site.select('div[@class="more_stats condensed_stats"]/ul/li/span[@class="data"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

source item.py :

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class MetacriticItem(Item):

# Here are the fields that will be crawled and stored
title = Field() # Game title
link = Field()  # Link to individual game page
cscore = Field() # Critic score
uscore = Field()   # User score
date = Field()  # Release date
```

my directory structure : [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbSFz.png)

Comment: my structure directory :

metacritic

Comment: I think the formatting should be fixed. I tried changing this, not sure why my review wasn't accepted.

Comment: do you have facebook bryans?
maybe u can answer from that

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. I was more concerned with getting the post showing code correctly so that more people might look at it.

Comment: ah i seee thanks :)

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570635/scrapy-importerror-no-module-named-items) though, it looks like your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your `item.py` into the second `metacritic` folder.