# Scrapy ImportError: No module named Item

Tags: python, scrapy

I know that this question was already widely discussed, but I didn't find an answer. I'm getting error **ImportError: No module named items**. I've created a new project with **$ scrapy startproject pluto** and I have no equal names (in names of project, classes etc), to avoid [problem with naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570635/scrapy-importerror-no-module-named-items).

*pluto_spider.py* :

```
import scrapy
from items import PlutoItem

class PlutoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "plutoProj"

  allowed_domains = ['successories.com']
  start_urls = [
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/4',
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/6',
        ]

def parse(self,response):

  items = []

  for quote in response.css('div.quotebox'):
    item = PlutoItem()
    item['author'] =  quote.css('span.author a::text').extract_first()
    item['quote'] = quote.css('div.quote a::text').extract_first()
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

*item.py* :

```
import scrapy

class PlutoItem(scrapy.Item):
  author = scrapy.Field()
  quote = scrapy.Field()
```

This my folder's hierarchy:

```
/pluto
/pluto/scrapy.cfg
/pluto/pluto/__init__.pyc
/pluto/pluto/__init__.py
/pluto/pluto/items.py
/pluto/pluto/pipelines.py
/pluto/pluto/settings.py
/pluto/pluto/settings.pyc
/pluto/pluto/spiders/__init__.py
/pluto/pluto/spiders/__init__.pyc
/pluto/pluto/spiders/pluto_spider.py
/pluto/pluto/spiders/pluto_spider.pyc
```

Comment: Is your module name `item.py` or `items.py`? I see you've referred to the same file by both names.

Comment: From which directory are you executing the `scrapy crawl xxx' (or any other command)?

Comment: Can you try `from pluto import items` and/or `import ..items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `items.py` and `pluto_spider.py` are at different levels. You should make your import either `from pluto import items` or a relative import `import ..items` per [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) to import the module.

If you want the class `from pluto.items import PlutoItem`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to *execute the Scrapy command from inside the top level directory of your project*.

Or you may also try changing your import to:

```
from pluto.items import PlutoItem
```