# Scrapy: cannot load items to spider

Tags: python, scrapy, namespaces, web-crawler, loading

I cannot load **scrapy** items to **scrapy** spiders. Here is my project structure:

```
-rosen
  .log
  .scrapers
    ..scrapers
      ...spiders
        ....__init__.py
        ....exampleSpider.py
      ...__init__.py
      ...items.py
      ...middlewares.py
      ...pipelines.py
      ...settings.py
  .src
    ..__init__.py
    ..otherStuff.py
  .tmp
```

This structure has been created using `scrapy startproject scrapers` inside of `rosen` project (directory).

Now, the `items.py` has the following code:

```
import scrapy
from Decimal import Decimal

class someItem(scrapy.Item):
   title: str = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
   bid: Decimal = scrapy.Field(serializer=Decimal)
```

And the `exampleSpider.py` has the following code:

```
import scrapy
from __future__ import absolute_import

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapers.scrapers.items import someItem

class someSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "some"

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self._some_fields = someItem()

   def parse(self, response) -> None: 
       some_loader = ItemLoader(item=self._some_fields, response=response)
       print(self._some_fields.keys())
```

The error I get is the following: **`runspider: error: Unable to load 'someSpider.py': No module named 'scrapers.scrapers'`**

I found [Scrapy: ImportError: No module named items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570635/scrapy-importerror-no-module-named-items) and tried all three solutions by renaming and adding `from __future__ import absolute_import`. Nothing helps. Please advice.

The **command** that I execute is `scrapy runspider exampleSpider.py`. I tried it from the `spiders` and `rosen` directories.

Comment: what command did you execute to run spider?

Comment: Added to the question, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Try `from ..items import someItem` instead of `from scrapers.scrapers.items import someItem`

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this as well and I get another error `runspider: error: Unable to load 'exampleSpider.py': attempted relative import with no known parent package`
`

Comment: @alienbeeq you need to run command `scrapy crawl some` that might work https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-crawl

Comment: Well, this is another method to run a code as per documentation. You can either `scrapy runspider` (in this option no need to create a scrapy project) or `scrapy crawl` specifying the name of the crawler. I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapers.scrapers'`

Answer (score 0):

i do not see any virtualenv inside your directory. So i recommend you to do so eg. under 'rosen'.
you can try this:

```
try:
    from scrapers.items import someItem
except FileNotFoundError:
    from scrapers. scrapers.items import someItem
```

then cal it with:

```
scrapy crawl NameOfSpider
```

or:

```
scrapy runspider path/to/spider.py
```